# How to find and replace using IF ISNUMBER in excel?

Tags: excel, replace

I have the text "`Primera DivisiÃ³`" and I am using this formula to find and replace the character/s `Ã³` with `ä` using the formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Ã³*",C30)),LEFT(C30,FIND("Ã³",C30) + 9) & "ä",C30)
```

in excel.

However I am getting `Primera DivisiÃ³ä`

What should be the correct formula to perform this function?

edit: How can add more than one arguments to replace more characters?

e.g. I would like to replace `Ã¤` with `ä` and `Ã¶` with `ö` in the same formula so that I can drag it down to all the rows in the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy can use `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Ã³","ä")
```

and you can nest multiple:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Ã³","ä"),"Ã¤","ä"),"Ã¶","ö")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Ã³*",D7)),REPLACE(D7,1,16, "ä"),D7)`

Edit: replacing with a more accurate solution

Comment: When I apply it to a cell with any value e.g. `Africa Cup of Nations` I get  the result as `ätions`

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Ã³*",D7)),REPLACE(D7,1,16, "ä"),D7)`  Are you trying to maintain the text around the entry also?